# Upload file into "assets" folder via move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

In Service Cloud (FKA RightNow) Customer Portal, isn't the "assets" folder writable?

I'm trying to upload a file to a subfolder inside the "assets" folder but I seem to be running into permission issues. The code I'm using is:

```
$file_name = "File_".time().".txt";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], HTMLROOT . '/euf/assets/uploads/text/'.$file_name))
{
    header("Location: /app/read_file/file_name/".$file_name);
    exit;
}
```

This is throwing an error which states:

> Access to move_uploaded_file is denied because its trying to access restricted folders in ......

Is there no way to save the uploaded file into the "assets" subfolder via PHP?

EDIT:

The destination seems to be correct as if I use:

```
echo HTMLROOT . '/euf/assets/uploads/text/'.$file_name
```

it prints:

```
/vhosts/sitename/euf/assets/upload/text/File_1480674311.txt
```

So the correct filepath is being referenced but somehow the framework is not allowing me to save it in there.

#### Update

The use case is such that via the CP, a person will upload a CSV/TXT file. This file would contain contact info (name, email etc) which will then be read (at a later stage) to create contacts in OSvC. This would be a recurring process, perhaps twice or thrice a month.

Since the reading of the file will not happen at the time of upload, storing the file someplace is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the folders are protected by user permissions that are enforced by WebDAV and the file system.  And, the assets folder is not intended to be a file storage mechanism for uploads as you are using in this capacity.

Is there a reason that you are placing files in assets as opposed to attaching them to incident or contact objects that would be within the context of someone operating within Customer Portal?

If you're looking to build some sort of content management into Customer Portal, then I'd suggest using a separate product for file storage that provides an API where you can manage files with more granularity, like Oracle Cloud Data Storage, where you can then serve these files from in CP.

Comment: Hi Scott. The use case is such that via the CP the client will upload a CSV/TXT file. This file would contain contact info (name, email etc) which will then be read (at a later stage) to create contacts in OSvC. This would be a recurring process. As suggested, I could store it as an Incident attachment, but I want to avoid having to create an Incident for this purpose. But if there is no other way to have a file uploaded to the file system, then I guess I'll have to think of a workaround. Oracle Cloud Data Storage is an option but that will cost extra $$ I think.

Comment: Per @Luke G's comments, this is not a practice that you should even consider implementing.  Even at the code level, you shouldn't store customer data in unprocted flat files on the FS; you would need to encrypt the files at the very least.  If you need to automate data transfers, then use the REST or SOAP web services to avoid the troubles that you will get into going down your current route.

Answer (score 1):

Storing contact records or any other sensitive data in **assets** folder is **VERY BAD PRACTICE**. These files are open to public as any other files stored in assets folder - css, js, images...

There are other folders in the file structure that are much better for this purpose. They are only accessible from the code level.

Are you by any chance on v16.8?

Comment: That's a good point. However, I'm not sure if any folders of the CP will have write permission enabled to allow for file uploads. Not sure about v16.8, but this is what I get from the Admin section `Build 619 SP 2, CP 619`

Comment: Here is how you can check the version you are on: YOURSITE.custhelp.com/ci/about

Comment: Same thing `Software Version: Oracle Service Cloud August 2016 (Build 619, CP 619) SP2`

Comment: August 2016 = 16.8 
When you upgrade to the next release this issue is likely to go away. Until then try to use different folders, for instance './custom' (also open to public).